# Time Series Comparison - Correlation and Regression Model

Tags: regression, time-series, correlation, inference, excel

I am trying to see if and how the news for affects the financial markets. I have a time-series for both of them.

Should I standardise the series? I have a monthly return on prices from the Dow and a monthly score for the sentiment, is that enough? I already tried to get the Standard Deviation for each month by using Excel and highlighting the days of each month (2000 - 2014) but it's taking too long `(=STDEV.S(B24:B42))`, so I'm wondering if its worth doing and if so, is there a faster way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: This is pretty broad, or at least parts of it are. You may or may not get a complete answer & some people may even vote to close. Thus, you may want to think about asking a series of concrete, focused questions. You can ask a new one as each is answered, & you could link between them for context. Note that tutorials & code help are off-topic.

Comment: @gung Thanks, I have removed the less important part of the questions. Please, see the edit.

Comment: You may want to roll that back. This is now definitely too broad & a good candidate for closure. The part of your initial question that looked best was asking if you needed to standardize the time series somehow. Just asking 'how to build... model' is not a good Q for CV.

Comment: That seems like it's probably a reasonable question. You may want to read some of our materials on asking questions here; you can find information in our [help/on-topic]. Since you're new here, you may also want to take our [tour].

Comment: Forget about this. You need to learn a lot about stock markets before you even start applying statistics. For one, you don't work with prices in these situations, but with returns.

Comment: @Aksakal Yes you are right, that was what I meant, I just keep calling it prices. Thanks.

Comment: @AdegokeA, prices do accommodate news, that's exactly how theory predicts markets work. However, they do so really quickly. I bet that your sentiment index is "too slow". By the time it's published, the markets absorbed the news weeks ago. You're not going to notice anything interesting in your series.

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that it is one thing to compute a correlation coefficient and yet another thing is how to test for independence or significance . Time series data does not qualify for standard textbook solutions which premise independent samples. http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/dbs202/cat/stats/corr.html . Another piece of literature which I wrote to illustrate the difference between cross-sectional data/tools and time series data/tools might help http://www.autobox.com/cms/index.php/afs-university/intro-to-forecasting?start=5 .It is entitled Regression vs Box-Jenkins.